# How to remove ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION from Expo - Still having my app rejected by Google

Tags: react-native, expo

I know this topic has been seen many times here. But even I been tried dozens of sugestions I read on the forum, My app is still been rejectd by google.
My app does not require background location, I have alread deleted expo-location and removed all the references from the code.

here is my app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Cold Mind App",
    "slug": "coldmindApp",
    "version": "1.0.1.7",
    "sdkVersion":"42.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ],
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover",
      "backgroundColor": "#000e1c"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": false
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "android": {
      "permissions": [],
      "package": "com.coldmind.autotradeapp",
      "adaptiveIcon":{
        "backgroundColor":"#000e1c",
        "foregroundImage":"./assets/icon.png"
      },
      "versionCode":15
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "expo": "~42.0.1",
    "expo-file-system": "~11.1.3",
    "expo-sharing": "~9.2.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "firebase": "8.2.3",
    "object-to-array-convert": "^1.1.0",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-42.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-image-viewing": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.4.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.11.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

And Here is Google Reply:

*** If you are targeting Android 10 or newer (SDK level 29 or higher):*
Remove the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission from your app APK or app bundle.*
If you’re using ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, examine your code paths and restrict usage to foreground purposes only. (learn more)*
You should no longer see the Location declaration listed in console under App Content.*
** If your are targeting Android 9 or older (SDK level 28 or lower):*
If you’re already using ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, examine your code paths and restrict usage to foreground purposes only. (learn more)*
In your console declaration, select “No” to the question “Does your app access location in the background in APKs or app bundles targeting Android 9 or older?*

Thanks!!!

Answer (score -1):

you tried to force remove?

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" tools:node="remove" />
```

supply inline your <manifest

```
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Comment: Hi. I am using Expo and do not have access direct to android manifest.... I think. How should I procedure? eject expo?

Comment: not being able to access the manifest directly, definitely a reason to abandon Expo